# Using "cached" LINQ entities

Tags: c#, sql, linq, wcf, linq-to-entities

i've got the problem that i implemented a WCF-service which is using LINQ entities... To generate the content of the response to a service call, requires a high amount of LINQ/SQL selects...

Whatever, the service is not doing any updates or inserts to the DB, so i'd like to implement a kind of "caching" of the LINQ entities ( also the DB-content is not growing in the millions... it will indeed be limited to about 63.000 mainentries ( with sub-dependancies ) like User -> Orders )

Also the service response does not have to contain the 100% up2date data, so updates of the data in the background shouldn't be anything to think about here

Ok, so currently my plan is as follows:

- Grab ALL the relevant tables from the database with LINQ so it has all the objects "cached" ( the ToList() function should do it, right? )
- Replace the entity object via a kind of smart threading every x-minutes/hours ( like grabbing the data from db again, lock the currently cached linq-DataContent and replace it with the new one.. )

So, what is your opinion... do you think i should/could do it like this? I really need to increase the responsetime of the service, but optimizing the SQL ( e.g. lesser amount of selects ) is not really an option for me, as all the LINQ stuff is already implemented..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like premature optimization to me. Consider:

1. There are *many* things which can slow down an app like this. DB queries may not be the slow part at all. If the slow part is L2E compilation, caching results is the *wrong* solution.
2. Doing cache invalidation correctly is usually harder than optimizing queries. There are, of course, exceptions.
3. The EF *already* caches entity instances in a context. Make sure you're not reinventing the wheel.

In other words, write *correct* code first, abstracted enough that you can plug in a cache if you have to (the Repository pattern is good for this). Profile it, find the slow parts, and fix those first.

Comment: Thanks! .. Referring to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707668/get-linq-to-preload-a-complete-table ... How would i realize it and make use of this cache..

Comment: That question is for L2S. Use Context.GetObjectByKey to avoid a new query if the object is already in the context. **But** like I said, this is probably not the slow part. Be careful to not optimize prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach you suggest is appropriate. Anyway, unless you are sure that *all* database registers in the relevant classes are always accessed, I would modify it so that instead of retrieving the whole tables at startup, it retrieves the registers the first time they are needed. Something like this:

```
GetRegister(id)
    if cache has not register with that id
        retrieve register from database
        store register in cache
    return cached register
```

This way you have your cache implemented, yet you are not wasting memory unnecessarily.

Comment: Yes, but don't i have the problem that the "first" request is as slow as it is now?

Comment: Yes, but the alternative (grabbing all the data upfront) will be even slower. Anyway that can be ok, depending on how your system is supposed to behave (make user wait a long time at application startup VS make it wait a little time for each first database request).

Comment: As it is a webservice it will run all the time, so i can waste some system resources.. thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Now an upvote would be nice (accepting the answer would be even better) :-)